# Why anchor button goes out of wrapper boundary?

Tags: html, css

My html anchor button goes out of wrapper boundary. When I define its height and width, it comes inside wrapper but I don't want to define height and width.

my html and css code are bellow

Link Example

```
<style>

    *
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    body
    {
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight:400;
    }
    .wrapper
    {
        width:500px;
        height:100px;
        margin:50px auto 0 auto;
        border:1px solid #000;
    }
    .btn-all
    {
        background:#666;
        padding:5px 10px;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .btn-all:hover
    {
        background:#900;
        color:#fff;
    }




</style>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="btn-all">Click Me</a>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Use `display: block` on anchor. See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/h6paLowg/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `a` is  `display` `inline` **element** and give to `a` **element** `display` property `inline-block` as like this

**Define to This**

```
.btn-all{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}
```

**Demo**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.btn-all {
  background: #666;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.btn-all:hover {
  background: #900;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="btn-all">Click Me</a>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
.btn-all
    {
        background:#666;
        padding:5px 10px;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;
        margin-top:20px;
        position:fixed;
        margin-left:20px;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/y6hr5xm7/1/)

Or 
[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/y6hr5xm7/2/)

css:

```
.btn-all
    {
        background:#666;
        padding:5px 10px;
        color:#fff;
        text-decoration:none;

        display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows how to have the link not extend out of the wrapper. It uses `display block` instead of `display inline-block` to not limit the width of the link to the content of the text, but to take up the full width of the container.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.btn-all {
  background: #666;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.btn-all:hover {
  background: #900;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="btn-all">Click Me</a>

  </div>
</body>
```